# One field in Django cannot retrieve the correct value when showing in template

Tags: python, html, django

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_OPTIONS = (
        ('VISA','VISA'),
        ('Master','Master'),
        ('Octopus','Octopus'),
        ('Cash','Cash'),
    )
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending','Pending'),
        ('Delivered','Delivered'),
        ('Collected','Collected'),
    )
    METHODS = (
        ('外賣自取','外賣自取'),
        ('送遞','送遞'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    card_id = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=7)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=PAYMENT_OPTIONS,null=True,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=STATUS,default='Pending')
    take_method = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=METHODS,null=True,blank=True)
    points_earned = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=350,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)+'\'s Order'
```

**views.py**

```
def checkout(request):
    global cartlist
    cartlist1 = cartlist
    total = 0
    for unit in cartlist:
        total += int(unit[3])
    grandtotal = total + 100
    earnings = int(grandtotal/5)
    print(grandtotal)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(type(request.POST.get('customerPayment')))
        print(request.POST.get('customerPayment'))
        print(request.POST.get('customerTakeaway'))
        customerName = request.POST.get('customerName','')
        customerID = request.POST.get('customerID','')
        customerMobile = request.POST.get('customerMobile','')
        customerEmail = request.POST.get('customerEmail','')
        customerPayment = request.POST.get('customerPayment'),
        customerTakeaway = request.POST.get('customerTakeaway'),
        customerAddress = request.POST.get('customerAddress','')
        new_order = Order.objects.create(
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.user),
                customer = customerName,
                card_id = customerID,
                mobile = customerMobile,
                email = customerEmail,
                total_price = grandtotal,
                payment_method = customerPayment,
                take_method = customerTakeaway,
                points_earned = earnings,
                address = customerAddress)
        account = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

**checkout.html**

```
<tr>
                        <td style="width:160px;text-align:center;">
                            <strong>付款方式</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="radio" name="customerPayment" value="VISA" id="customerPayment">VISA
                            <input type="radio" name="customerPayment" value="Master" id="customerPayment">Master<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="customerPayment" value="Octopus" id="customerPayment">Octopus
                            <input type="radio" name="customerPayment" value="Cash" id="customerPayment">Cash
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:160px;text-align:center;">
                            <strong>領取方式</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="radio" name="customerTakeaway" value="外賣自取" id="customerTakeaway">外賣自取
                            <input type="radio" name="customerTakeaway" value="送遞" id="customerTakeaway">送遞
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

**order_summary.html**

```
<tr>
                    <td style="width:160px;text-align:center;">
                        <strong>付款方式</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
                        {{ customer_order.payment_method }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:160px;text-align:center;">
                        <strong>領取方式</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
                        {{ customer_order.take_method }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

When I try to submit the form in the `checkout` method, since I have the `Order` model having the CharFields with choices and I used `request.POST.get(field_name)` that is the radiobuttons from the HTML. After I submitted the form, the `{{ customer_order.payment_method }}` shows `('VISA',)` instead of the correct value `VISA` and the database record could not update that record. Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using any of Django's built-in form validation, or even a form on your checkout page (unless it was cut off in the snippet you pasted).

Typically you would have a `<form method="post"></form>` with a csrf token and the inputs as child elements at minimum.

See [Part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial04/) of the official Django tutorial for an example of this.

Also, your radio inputs should be labeled properly:

```
<input type="radio" name="customerPayment" value="VISA" id="customerPayment">
<label for="customerPayment">VISA</label>
```

That may be impacting how the post data is sent to the server.

Alternatively you can use Django forms themselves to build your form with Python code. This adds the built-in validation I mentioned earlier. It also offers the ChoiceField, which is built specifically for model choices and handles the validation for you.

Then instantiate the unbound form and pass it into your view as context if the request method is get.

And in your view if the method is post, check if the form is valid with `form.is_valid()` and optional additional cleaning of the values with `form.cleaned_data`.

I recommend reading further on the basics of Django forms in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/).